# Setting End Date to same as start date

Tags: form, date-time

I have a list that I created to track start/end times for activities. I'd like to set the form so that when the user enters the start date it populates the end with the same date so that users ONLY have to enter/select the date once.

[image]

Comment: You could add javascript. On lose focus on the first field, set the second field to the same value. Or, if you set both to today by default, when they change the first one it will adjust the second.

Comment: do users have the choice to change the end date if they wanted to?

Comment: I'm happy to add javascript, just not sure what the script would be. Currently, users do have the choice to change the end date.. but I don't want them to.

Comment: have a look at my answer if that suits your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can save below code in a JS file in a document library and set that file as JSLink to End date field:

```
        (function () {
            // jQuery library is required in this sample 
            // Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
            (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>'));

            var EndDateFieldSelector = "table[id^=EndDate]";
            $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('a').attr('onclick', 'return false;');

            var StartDateFieldSelector = "table[id^=StartDate]";
            $(StartDateFieldSelector).find('input').change(function () {
                $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('input').val($(this).val());
                $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('select')[0].val($(StartDateFieldSelector).find('select')[0]);
                $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('select')[1].val($(StartDateFieldSelector).find('select')[1]);
            });

            $(StartDateFieldSelector).find('select').change(function () {
                $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('input').val($(EndDateFieldSelector).find('input').val());
                $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('select')[0].val($(StartDateFieldSelector).find('select')[0]);
                $(EndDateFieldSelector).find('select')[1].val($(StartDateFieldSelector).find('select')[1]);
            });
        })();
```

This code will:
1. Disable EndDate TextBox, Drop-downs and Calender link
2. Copy the values of StartDate TextBox and Drop-downs to EndDate TextBox, Drop-downs

Answer (score 0):

This might fulfill your requirements (no javascript needed - OOB solution) :

1.Add a new field of type calculated to the list and set it equal to the start date field (your formula should look like : =[name of the start date field])
set the return type of the calculated field to Date time (Date only)

2.reivew the list data to check that end date is set as expected for all items

3.delete the original end date field from the list